# SwiftUI preview Crash when using tasks on a view (when supporting iOS 14)

Tags: ios, swiftui

I encountered something that seems like a bug in Xcode/SwiftUI that's easy to reproduce:
In a Swift Package, depending on the supported platform, I get a crash upon tapping the button in a preview. iOS 14 -> Crash iOS 15 + -> No issue

Here is the package.swift for repro

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "PreviewCrashDemo",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14)], // Changing this to iOS 15 fixes the crash ><
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "PreviewCrashDemo",
            targets: ["PreviewCrashDemo"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "PreviewCrashDemo",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

And here is the code for my preview:

```
struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Button("Hello world") {
                Task {
                    print("Hi!")
                }
            }
            .previewDisplayName("Crash on iOS 14")
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Check code, simple things preview not working for iOS 14 but ok for iOS 15.

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in **Xcode 14.3** ([Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes#Resolved-Issues)).

> Fixed: Previews can fail when using Swift Concurrency in an app with a minimum deployment target of <= iOS 14.0. (99969698)

Try this version or higher.